# Altair ALT1160 Chipset

Tags: wireless, wireless-adapter

I am hearing about this low cost LTE modem designed for the Raspberry Pi. The modem is [Altair's ALT1160](https://altair-semi.com/products/alt1160/). I hear that [it costs $15 to $20 to make](https://www.pcworld.com/article/3145614/computers/raspberry-pi-3-gets-low-bandwith-lte-with-add-on-chip.html).

Here is where I am confused. The only places where I can find prices for this chip are from the manufacturer's page linked above as ALT1160. These are starter kits and can easily cost from $70 to over $100. Unless I am missing something, I would think a reseller would sell the chip by itself. My goal is to find a relatively cheap LTE chip (in the $30 range if possible).

Of course, I could just be wrong and the chip does not get sold by itself, except in bulk. If it is sold by itself, where would I be able to find it. If not, I will have to look for cheap alternatives.

Comment: This question falls into the category of looking for shopping advice which is strictly off-topic.

Comment: For those interested in bulk orders of chipsets, not the 1160 specifically, bur other ones. I have found https://iotdevices.att.com/iot-accelerator.aspx through http://www.sequans.com/products-solutions/streamlitelte/monarch-lte-platform/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the Raspberry Pi CPU , at this juncture, it appears that this company does not provide this part through any distributors.

Your best bet is to purchase the development board or to contact them directly for samples.

I'm sorry to say the cost you quote is for a volume design and not possible for a one-off unless you manage to scrounge some samples for free (still need a PCB)

I did a check of some second market resellers and they do not even know about this chip. It is likely manufactured to order and thus can only be obtained from the MFG at this point.

---

When you go to the manufacturer site, what you are seeing are "development boards", they are pricier and usually larger than a consumer board, they are also sold in much lower quantity.

They tend to expose *all* the features of the device, to will help evaluate your design.

---

In this particular case, the part you are looking at is an `ASIC` and not a general purpose part like an ADC, or microcontroller.

Usually, a device manufacturer will only sell directly to very large customers and distributors.

However, `ASIC` Markets and companies are stil small and rather new, so it is more common that they only deal directly.